# egrep not giving result full path in for loop

Tags: linux

I have a simple script return full path if it found in egrep.  However it returns only count for each file.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in `/logs/*`
do

  egrep "Warning" $file | wc -l ;
done
```

Comment: What do you expect \`/logs/*\` to do?

Comment: I'm new to Linux script.  I'm trying to find "Warning" in any logs then display log full path and log file name. Else do nothing.

Comment: Try removing the back-ticks ...

Comment: `return full path if it found` what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

> return full path if it found in egrep

To return the filenames of files that contain the string `Warning` from files inside `logs/*` just do:

```
grep -l "Warning" /logs/*
```

The `-l` option to makes grep output only the filenames that match the regex, see [man grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep). The `/logs/*` expands to the list of all filenames inside the `/logs/` directory, see [bash filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion).

Please don't use `egrep`. According to man `egrep` is deprecated and `grep -E` is preferred. The `Warning` is a plain text without any significant regular expressions - there is no need to parse it as an [extended regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html).

Please don't use ` backticks, they are [discouraged](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). The `$(...)` process substitution is preferred.